# How to transition from non-angular login page to angular homepage

Tags: javascript, protractor

My company is starting to build all of our websites using Angular, and after fighting with Java Webdriver to navigate these new pages, I decided to give Protractor a shot.

The login page is not in Angular, but I think I figured that out by setting `ignoreSynchronizatyion = true`.

What I'd like to do is simply confirm the presence of our website's homepage's Title after logging in, but the homepage is in Angular.  So I tried a few different variations of setting `ignoreSynchronizatyion = false` but I'm obviously doing something wrong.

```
describe('angular web navigation', function() {

it('should login and confirm title', function() {
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
browser.get('https://website.com/login')

browser.driver.findElement(by.name('username')).sendKeys("123456");
browser.driver.findElement(by.name('submit')).click;

browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
expect(element(by.model('title')).getText()).
    toEqual('Expected Title');
  });
});
```

Any tips on logging in on a non-Angular page and then confirming the presence of an Angular element?

Comment: Is the url also changing after the submit? If so, you can wait on the url to change and then enable the synchronisation and get the text

Comment: How did you end up solving this in the end? I have exactly the same situation and I have it mostly working, but where you have "expect(element(by.model('title'...." I'm trying to do the same thing on my angular page after the non-angular login and I"m getting "timed out waiting for angular tasks to finish" or "no such element found".

Comment: @S.Huston sorry for the formatting ... I did browser.driver.findElement(by.name('submit')).click().then(function () {
      browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
    });

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you need to call the `click()` method, replace:

```
browser.driver.findElement(by.name('submit')).click;
```

with:

```
browser.driver.findElement(by.name('submit')).click();
```

Then, if turning the sync off does not work this way, do at in the `click()` promise resolution step:

```
browser.driver.findElement(by.name('submit')).click().then(function () {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly. However i had to create 2 different versions to avoid the wrong user/pass case :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `browser.driver.findElement('..')` AND `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true`; is double. See the [docs here](http://www.protractortest.org/#/webdriver-vs-protractor).
If you need to automate a non-Angular page you have 2 options:

1. If you still want to use the protractor syntax (`element(by.css('')`), you can use `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;`. This will disable the waiting for Angular on a non-Angular page. This results in this example

```js
describe('angular web navigation', function() {
  it('should login and confirm title', function() {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.get('https://website.com/login');

    element(by.name('username')).sendKeys("123456");
    element(by.name('submit')).click()
      .then(function() {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
      });

    expect(element(by.model('title')).getText())
      .toEqual('Expected Title');
  });
});
```

2. If you don't want to use `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;`, what I personally prefer because it could give some troubles with future releases of Protractor and it's a better distinction between Angular and non-Angular code, you can also use the "Vanilla WebDriver" `browser`-object, see [here](http://www.protractortest.org/#/webdriver-vs-protractor)

```js
describe('angular web navigation', function() {
  it('should login and confirm title', function() {
    browser.driver.get('https://website.com/login');

    browser.driver.findElement(by.name('username')).sendKeys("123456");
    browser.driver.findElement(by.name('submit')).click();

    expect(element(by.model('title')).getText())
      .toEqual('Expected Title');
  });
});
```